# WindowHandles not working on IE: Not switching to new tab

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I need to open a link in a new tab and get back to the original tab; however, it seems like the WindowHandle is not working properly. The code below only opens a new tab and then loads the link in the original tab without switching to it.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bi7-azure.accenture.com/");
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
```

[image]

Alternatively, I read that there is a new feature that does this in a much easier and simple way, but it doesn't work as well (I'm missing a dependency or something), and I don't see a lot of articles about it. It would be great if there's a way I can use this instead, or if not then how can I overcome the issue with WindowHandles. Please note as well that I've already configured IE properly and added the necessary registry edit as per most of the forums on the internet says.

```
driver.SwitchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
```

I know there are duplicate questions for this, but most of them are old so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
          public static string SwitchToTab()
    {
        var mainHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        var handles = driver.WindowHandles;

        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            if (mainHandle == handle)
            {
                continue;
            }
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            break;
        }
        var result = Url;
        return result;
    }
```

Then...

```
        public static void GoToMainHandle()
    {
        var handles = driver.WindowHandles;
        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            break;
        }
    }
```

you can also use:

```
        public static void CloseTab()
    {
        var mainHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        var handles = driver.WindowHandles;
        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            if (mainHandle == handle)
            {
                continue;
            }
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            driver.Close();
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(mainHandle);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait for the window to be loaded, before you switch to that window. Here's an extension method, that will do that:

```
public static SwitchToWindow(this IWebDriver @this, string windowTitle)
    {
        var tryCount = 0;
        while (!@this.WindowHandles.Any(x => @this.SwitchTo().Window(x).Title.StartsWith(windowTitle)))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            if (tryCount == 60)
                throw new NoSuchWindowException($"No window with title {windowTitle} found.");
            tryCount=+1;
        }
        @this.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
```